# Use WordPress default text domain for translating labels

Tags: translation, textdomain

I am wondering if there is a way to use the "default" text domain ("WordPress" or "default") to translate labels. E.g I have following code:

```
// Register Custom Taxonomy
function custom_taxonomy() {

$labels = array(
    'name'                       => _x( 'Press category', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'my_text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'              => _x( 'Press category', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'my_text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'                  => __( 'Pressekateorien', 'my_text_domain' ),
    'all_items'                  => __( 'All Items' ),
    'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Item' ),
    'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Item:' ),
    'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Item Name' ),
    'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Item' ),
    'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Item' ),
    'update_item'                => __( 'Update Item' ),
    'view_item'                  => __( 'View Item' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate items with commas' ),
    'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove items' ),
    'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used' ),
    'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Items' ),
    'search_items'               => __( 'Search Items' ),
    'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found' ),
);
$args = array(
    'labels'                     => $labels,
    'hierarchical'               => true,
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => false,
);
register_taxonomy( 'category_press', array( 'press' ), $args );

}

// Hook into the 'init' action
add_action( 'init', 'custom_taxonomy', 0 );
```

As you can see, I am only translating 3 strings ("name", "singular name" and "menu_name" with *my_text_domain*, the other ones should be translated by the default text domain that WordPress is using in the backend anyway). WPML for example shows me there is a *WordPress* text domain. I tried to use that as well, but neither *default* or *WordPress* works, e.g. I tried:

```
'all_items'                  => __( 'All Items', 'WordPress' ), // doesn't work
'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Item', 'default' ), // doesn't work
```

Any hints?

THANKS!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't provide any textdomain, WordPress translated strings are used. If you use, for example, `__( 'Add New Tag' );`, the translation from WordPress core will be used because `'Add New Tag'` exists in WordPress.

Your problem is that your are defining labels that don't exist in WordPress core, so they are not included in any WordPress translation files. I mean, strings like `'All Items'` or `'Popular Items'` don't exist in WordPress and they are not translated anywhere.

I think my explanation is a little tricky, I hope you get what I mean.

Comment: HI cybmeta, oh alright. I see, I actually assumed that "All Items", "Popular Items" etc. are pretty much standard terms since I used the Taxonomy Generator from Generate WP (http://generatewp.com/taxonomy/). I will have to check for the "general" termns in the localization files. Thank you!